# Google Guava / Equivalence / different equals() and hashCode() method implementations

Tags: java, guava

I want to be able to switch between two equals-Implementations, but I'm not sure if the `Equivalence` class of Google Guava maybe provides this functionality. Let's say I have two equals methods equalsContent() and equalsKeys() or something like that I somehow want to delegate the equals method to one of the two private methods (and the same for the two hashCode methods).

Well, I'm somehow not sure what the usage of the `Equivalence` abstract class and the `Equivalences` class (static methods) is.

Besides, how would you implement the desired properties described above? I could use another method which simply sets a flag or an enum to the value and implement the two equals and hash methods inside an enum with two abstract methods (equals(), hashCode()) and simply call enum.equals() or enum.hashCode() in the equals() and hashCode() method. What do you think?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the enum approach would make sense from an object-oriented point of view, but it's dangerous. It could break the `equals()` and `hashCode()` contract (reflexivity, symmetry, and transitivity). For example, inserting an instance that uses the first equivalence strategy and an instance that uses the second equivalence strategy in the same `Set` would cause problems.

If you want different equivalence relationships, you should keep those out of your class. `Equivalence` lets you do just that: you extract the equivalence logic (equals() / hashCode()) by implementing Equivalence and overriding the `doHash()` and `doEquivalent()` methods.

Then, when you want to use a `Collection` based on one equivalence or the other, you use `Equivalence.wrap()`. For example, you could emulate an `IdentityHashSet` by doing:

```
Set<Equivalence.Wrapper<String>> identityHashSet = Sets.newHashSet();

String a1 = "a";
String a2 = new String("a");
String b = "b";

identityHashSet.add(Equivalences.identity().wrap(a1));
identityHashSet.add(Equivalences.identity().wrap(a2));
identityHashSet.add(Equivalences.identity().wrap(a3));

// identityHashSet contains "a", "a", and "b"
// a standard HashSet would only contain "a" and "b"
// while a1 and a2 are equal according to String.equals(), they are different instances.
```

Of course, you could use `ForwardingSet` to automate the wrapping / unwrapping of your elements.

There is more info in [this Guava issue](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=576).

Comment: True, thanks, I didn't even know of the Wrapper, but maybe that might be because I just updated Guava from r09 to 10 ;-)

Comment: How could you use `ForwardingSet` to automate wrapping/unwrapping? If your class extends `ForwardingSet<Wrapper<E>>`, it can't also implement `Set<E>`.

Comment: Good point. You would need to implement the forwarding pattern yourself. `ForwardingSet` might be useful as an inspiration when doing that, though.